# HTML - XML: how to solve an ParseError (text)

Tags: python, xml, jupyter

Recently I started to learn web access, service and XML from Jupyter Notebook and I ran to an Traceback that is unclear for me how to solve it.  Could someone give me a direction to figure out the solution?

Here is the code:

```python
import re
import string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML read as XML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>HTML file</h1>
        </header>
            <person>
                <name> Madderman </name>
                <phone type='local'> 
                            088 043 04 30
                </phone>
            </person>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Some stuff</th>
                    <td>Value/ Element</td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><Some stuff with other stuff</th>
                    <td>Value /element</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <script></script>
    </body>
</html> """

check = ET.fromstring(data)  # This code import the data by directly reading from a string which is the root element of the parsed tree

print('Name', check.find('name').text) <br>
print('Phone', check.find('phone').text)
```

Here is the TraceBack:
[File "/home/jupyterlab/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML  parser.feed(text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIHIt.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ Luke Woodward Thanks for formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document is invalid.

`<th><Some stuff with other stuff</th>`

See the `<` you have before the word `Some`

---

You should use the proper xpath

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML read as XML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>HTML file</h1>
        </header>
            <person>
                <name> Madderman </name>
                <phone type='local'> 
                            088 043 04 30
                </phone>
            </person>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Some stuff</th>
                    <td>Value/ Element</td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Some stuff with other stuff</th>
                    <td>Value /element</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <script></script>
    </body>
</html> """

check = ET.fromstring( data) 


print('Name', check.find('.//name').text)
print('Phone', check.find('.//phone').text)
```

output

```
Name  Madderman 
Phone  
                            088 043 04 30
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. But I am running now to the Traceback :
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-10c3f0d9091c> in <module>
     37 
     38 check = ET.fromstring(data)
---> 39 print('Name', check.find('name').text)
     40 print('Email', check.find('email').get('hide'))
     41 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'